How can I make a Roblox friend request?
Code changes for the changed Roblox Friends API
I am trying to make a Roblox friend requester for Python, but this is not fully working to request a Roblox friend API.
import requests

rcookie = "Example Cookie" # Security COOKIE
Target_ID = 1 # Roblox

x_csrf_res = requests.post(
    url = "https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/1/users",
    cookies = {
        ".ROBLOSECURITY": rcookie
    }
)

if x_csrf_res.headers.get("x-csrf-token"):
    csrf = x_csrf_res.headers.get("x-csrf-token")
    test_res = requests.post(
        url = f"https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/{Target_ID}/request-friendship",
        data = {
            "friendshipOriginSourceType": 0
        },
        headers = {
            "X-Csrf-Token": csrf
        },
        cookies = {
            ".ROBLOSECURITY": rcookie
        }
    )
    if test_res.status_code == 200:
        print("Send Friend!")
        print(test_res.text)
    else:
        print("Error!")
        print(test_res.status_code)
        print(test_res.text)
else:
    print(f"Invalid Cookie! {x_csrf_res.status_code} {x_csrf_res.text}")

Even if the response code is 200 in Roblox, the friend request is not requested.
This is the proof photo.



{
    "success": true,
    "notificationMuted": true
}

However, when requesting the same data to Postman, the retuned JSON is the following.
{
    "success": true,
    "isCaptchaRequired": false
}

This successfully works to request a Roblox friend API and a friend request comes in the target Roblox user ID..
How can I fix this problem?
My code has been broken since the Roblox Friends API changed.
